# Having two System.Timer.Timer objects in your class and catching exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, system.timers.timer

I have a class with two `System.Timers.Timer` objects. What I see now, is that an exception thrown in one, is caught by the other. Is that correct behaviour?

```
class MyClass {
    System.Timers.Timer tOne;
    System.Timers.Timer tTwo;

    tOne.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(one);
    tTwo.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(two);

    void one(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        try {
             .. some code that throws ...
        } catch (Exception) {
               // not caught here
        }
    }

    void two(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        try {
        } catch (Exception) {
               // but caught here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off running your timers in separate threads tbh

Comment: Can you post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What you're claiming is impossible. If both of your timer references same instance, then it's possible (if you don't have try/catch block in first handler).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that's why I ask. I see weird stuff happening in my code. An MVCE will be hard I am afraid.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel if I break on the exception thrown and check the stack, there is no reference to where the error actually occurs.

Comment: Strange!. Break when exception thrown should stop at the exact line where the exception occurs. Of course VS will get confused when some native code throws unexpected exceptions. Is that the case?

Comment: I dont think it is possible to find out unles OP gives more specific code of function one and two

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. Both methods use the same thread-unsafe object. I removed one `Timer` and put both calls to the methods `one` and `two` in one call and it seems to be fixed. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't because I have two timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different timers, but the exception is caught by the first timer that `ticks` after the exception is thrown. Your problem is mainly because you use a single
 thread.

`System.Timers.Timer` will silently swallow exceptions and continue the timer (although this is subject to change in future versions of the framework); `System.Threading.Timer` will terminate the program.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question.

Comment: He asked if it is the correct behaviour. In that context, it is correct from what I see, because each timer has his own thread and by that, it calls his own method. The exception is caught in other timer, you have multi-threading and no other sync mechanism.